# Singleton or Static class

Tags: java, android, static, singleton

i have 2 Data-Classes to store some Values. The First Class (Custom1) has a variable of type Custom2.

I want to fill the variables through different activities and store the information into an sql-Database.

Main -> Activity1 (Var1 filled) -> Activity2 (Var 2 filled) -> Activity3 (Var 4 filled) -> SQL.

To fill the Var3 (of type Custom2) i wanted to implement a service, because the data is fetched from the Internet. (Called in Activity 1 -> time to get the data while user fills data in activity 2 -> stored in SQL at the end of Activity3)

Now i think about implementing a singleton class where all data is written to (from the 3 activities and the service) and which values are stored into SQL at the end. Is this the best way to do this?

Or should i just create a static Custom1 at Main.onCreate()? I tried to research which way will work the best, but i'm not sure about it. Because the Custom1&Custom2 classes have about 22 variables together, i wanted to avoid Copy&Paste from the Custom1 Class to a Singleton Class.

Passing an Instance of Custom1 through the Activities doesn't sound a good idea, because i need acces to the data from within the service.

Anybody some tips? I know this is nearly a frequently asked question, but with the favor answer "It depends" i just tried to make my needs clear on that.

Thank you!

```
public class Custom1{
 private String Var1;
 private Int Var2;
 private Custom2 Var3;
 private String var4;

 public void Custom1(){ }

//getter & setter
}

public class Custom2{
 private double Var5;

 public void Custom2(){}

//getter & setter
}
```

Comment: Learn Observers and observable implementation

Comment: That may not answer your question, but have you considered using `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Not yet. This is used as a cache therefore i didn't think about the sharedpreferences, but it could be an option. I'll give it a try - is there any performanceissue in storing and retrieving data from SharedPreferences instead of an object?

Thanks Sheychan, i heard about observers long time ago, i definitly have a look at them.

Comment: So talking about the Observer, just to get it right:
Actually, only Activity3 needs the data, because that is the place where the saveToSQL-method will be called. I didn't care about onChanged, because the user initiates the save procedure. Is the Observer pattern also used that all the Subscribers can edit the Subject? I didn't think that this is the main idea of this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the data in singleton is the best approach for this scenario. `SharedPreferences` is stored on disk so it is unnecessary overhead. Once you reach the final activity you can check whether singleton is finished loading or not by checking some flag that service can set. If it is then write into SQL otherwise create a broadcast listener which will listen to service finishing the task and then write into SQL.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good. To create the Singleton - can i somehow reference to the Custom class (e.g. extend or somethin) or is it really just copy&paste the variable definitions and getter/setter methods (plus creating additional methods like private constructor and so on)?

Comment: You can use the Custom class itself, no need to extend anything. Singleton can be any class which is formed in a way that only once instance can be created by making the constructor as private and using that one instance multiple times.

Comment: Right, but i also want to use this Class when i retrieve the data from the SQL (Class = diary entry; SQL = many diary entries) - and because i want to store different entries into an ArrayList<Custom1>, i need also a non-singleton copy of the class, or am i wrong?

Comment: Ya think of custom class as a model where you read/write data using getter setters. Create a singleton which creates objects of this class and fills data. No need to extend the custom class just make all the variabls private with access from getters and setters only.